# Count the number of occurness before certain date

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

In MySQL I have a table of records with these columns:
id,date,voucher_id,person_id

example db

```
id         Date         voucher_id   person_id
-----      ------       ----------   ----------
0          2016-02-17   null         1
1          2016-02-18   null         1
2          2016-02-19   1            1
3          2016-02-20   2            2
4          2016-02-21   null         2
5          2016-02-22   3            2
6          2016-02-23   null         1
7          2016-02-24   4            1
8          2016-02-24   null         3
9          2016-02-25   null         3
```

And I want to know the list of persons that uses vouchers and count how many times that person have record in my table before the usage day of that voucher.

The result for about table would be:

```
 Date         voucher_id   person_id    count_till_now
 ------       -------      ----------   --------------
 2016-02-19   1            1            2
 2016-02-20   2            2            0
 2016-02-22   3            2            1
 2016-02-24   4            1            4
```

Which is the best query for generating this result?

Comment: Is the `Date` field the 'usage day' of the voucher? If so, then why are there `null` entries in the `voucher_id` column?

Comment: Some users may use _voucher_ and some may not. It's like a gift card in my application. If a user have a voucher will use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT `Date`, voucher_id, person_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t2.person_id = t1.person_id AND
              t2.`Date` < t1.`Date`) AS count_till_now
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE t1.voucher_id IS NOT NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6c45f/3)

Alternatively you can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.`Date`, t1.voucher_id, t1.person_id, 
       COUNT(t2.person_id) AS count_till_now
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id AND t1.`Date` > t2.`Date`
WHERE t1.voucher_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.`Date`, t1.voucher_id, t1.person_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6c45f/7)